# Which logistic model is appropriate for longitudinal data?

Tags: r, logistic, panel-data

I have data in longitudinal or clustered format (please see the example below). My response variable is dichotomous. I want to examine which factors explains why a subject in the dataset gets Y=1. In the example below I show only one predictor – X.

Since I have a dichotomous response variable, I am thinking of logistic regression. However, the longitudinal format violates the distributional assumption of ML-theory. **So my question is which logistic model would be appropriate here?** And if possible, which R-package would be relevant (if not covered by the standard stats)?

All subjects are countries and observed (let's say) from 1990-1994. A country can get more than 1 Y per year, from different Z's.  I have been thinking of logistic panel models. Although I am not sure which specific model would be appropriate (assuming that panel models are more appropriate group of models). Perhaps random effects as each observation is not of the same nature (a country can get Y=1 from different groups, see variable Z). The Z variable is not a part of analysis though. Grateful for all suggestions!

```
COUNTRY      YEAR  Y           X        Z

    A        1990  0           0        K
    A        1991  1           0        K
    A        1992  0           0        K
    A        1993  1           0        L
    B        1994  0           1        L
    B        1990  0           1        L
    B        1991  0           1        L
    B        1992  1           1        L
    C        1990  1           0        K
    C        1991  1           0        K
    C        1992  0           0        L
    C        1993  0           1        K
    C        1994  0           1        L
    D        1990  0           1        L
    D        1991  0           0        K
    D        1992  0           0        K
    D        1993  0           1        K
    D        1994  0           1        K
```

Comment: It seems you can do  mixed effect (random effect, multilevel, bla, bla..)logistic model

Comment: Thanks @DeepNorth Could you elaborate just a little why you think mixed effect is more appropriate?

Comment: It is from the i.i.d assumption might not hold, especially the independent of samples might not hold for the repeated measurement such as countries. You also can think of  multilevel/cluster , i.e. within a county or cluster  individuals were not independent. Then mixed models  decompose variance to some extant make them  i.id but then based on another assumption . Anyway it all about i.i.d assumption.